# Multiple Dependent Drop Down Lists based on Database

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vba

I have an Excel database of component costs that is laid out as follows in a sheet.

**Vendor    -     Category  --  Component    -- Price**

Vendor A    Category A  Component A  $5.00

Vendor A    Category A  Component B  $8.00

Vendor A    Category B  Component A  $9.00

Vendor A    Category B  Component B  $11.00

Vendor B    Category A  Component A  $14.00

Vendor B    Category C  Component A  $14.00

Vendor B    Category C  Component B  $17.00

Vendor B    Category D  Component A  $6.00

Vendor C    Category C  Component C  $7.00

Vendor C    Category D  Component A  $4.00

Vendor C    Category D  Component B  $12.00

What I am trying to do is have a user come in and build a piece of equipment that is made up of different components. That user would use a drop down list to choose the vendor, then another drop down list to choose the category, then finally use another drop down list to choose the component. (that is based on the vendor and category) From these, the price would be populated into the sheet as well.

The empty sheet would look something like this...

**Vendor ------------ Type ------- Component ---- Cost -------    Quantity -------  Extended Cost**

(drop down) -- (drop down) -- (drop Down) -- VLOOKUP

Populating the price doesn't seem too hard, except it is based on multiple criteria. VLOOKUP for that. My main problem is 1) creating the drop down list from the column that has multiple repeats as it is database format and 2) using multiple dependent drop downs.

Thank you!

Comment: Whatever Your database maybe, the design should let you fill the Drop down with distinct values!

Comment: The database is just an Excel database.

Answer (score 0):

assuming there are no duplicates in the data list (e.g. `Vendor A Category A Component A` can't appear twice)

a Sumproduct or a SUMIFS (depending on excel version) gives you the value

**SUMIFS**:
Sumifs will return the price when the vendor is equal to A2, the Category/Type is equal to B2, and the Componenet is equal to C2

```
=SUMIFS(Data!D:D,Data!A:A,A2,Data!B:B,B2,Data!C:C,C2)
```

**SUMPRODUCT**:
Sumproduct works better with fixed size ranges, as multiplying 16,384 or 1,000,000+ rows takes a much longer time

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Data!D1:D999,--(Data!A1:A999=A2),--(Data!B1:B999=B2),--(Data!C1:C999=C2))
```